# Creating spatial population heat map

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I have some data that contains crab males population based on latitude and longitude. I am trying to plot the population distribution on map (not point density). For example I like to show which areas are more populated and where less.
Here is my data

```
     lon    lat NUM_MALES_KEPT
1 144.35 -41.51              4
2 144.35 -41.52             22
3 144.39 -41.56              3
4 144.38 -41.53              5
5 144.38 -41.52              3
6 144.37 -41.54             10
```

I used `geom_density` code but this code maps data based on point density not population density.

Comment: Could you please explain the distinction you are trying to make between "point density" and "population density"?  And what kind of map are you trying to create?  A point map, a choropleth map, a contour map, something else?

Comment: I want to draw contour map that shows different areas that have different population. something like kriging method.

Comment: That's not what kriging does. You don't really think there exist positive numbers of males at *every* point on a map, do you? But that's what it would indicate. How to make an accurate map depends on what these data mean--that is, whether they are an exhaustive census (which seems unlikely) or samples. And if they are samples of a population, the mapping method has to depend on the methods used to select the sample locations and observe the crabs. Of course you could ignore these issues and make a contour map of your data--but you could not legitimately claim it has any meaning or accuracy.

Comment: I have another question. Is google map accurate? I mean that if we map GPS data which we gained from high accurate GPS data, are they accurate in google map?

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfexp, aes(lon, lat)) + 
  borders() + 
  xlim(c(144.325, 144.40)) + ylim(c(-41.575, -41.5)) + 
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom="polygon") +
  geom_point(position="jitter", alpha=.2, colour="white")
```

[image]

---

Or using `ggmap` (as requested):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map(make_bbox(c(144.325, 144.4), c(-41.57, -41.48), f=0.2))
ggmap(map) +  
  aes(x=lon, y=lat) + 
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), dfexp, geom="polygon") + 
  geom_point(data=dfexp, position="jitter", alpha=.2, colour="white")
```

[image]

---

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="     lon    lat NUM_MALES_KEPT
1 144.35 -41.51              4
2 144.35 -41.52             22
3 144.39 -41.56              3
4 144.38 -41.53              5
5 144.38 -41.52              3
6 144.37 -41.54             10")
library(splitstackshape)
dfexp <- expandRows(df, "NUM_MALES_KEPT")
```

Comment: How I can plot it on a map with ggmap command?

Comment: Have a look at my edit

Comment: Great. Feel free to check it (= marking as solved) if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks. There is a problem. the legend shows level from 0.05 to 0.30. but the level of my data is from 1 to 230. How I can fix it?